# jQuery - Using Load & Updating the URL in the Address Bar while supporting the Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a web app with jQuery & Rails. The web app loads pages with AJAX ... no page refresh.

When a user clicks on a link to load a new page via AJAX, i want to update the address bar. I also want to maintain the browser's back button support.

ideas?

Comment: I've tried "window.history.pushState" but that updates the URL but doesn't refresh the page, so the URL is right but the AJAX content driven stuff is stale... And I hear it won't be supported by IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same demand on a project, this feature is called Deep link.

You just have to use a jQuery plugin called Address http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, it makes everything easy. There is a wonderful documentation and examples on the site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Link to e.g. `#page1` or `#page2`; this will keep you on the same page
2. Bind a function to these links that retrieves the `window.location.hash`
3. Load the relevant data, depending on the retrieved hash info

Comment: so update the URL to a HASH.... but then if that gets bookmarked, how does the browser know what to do with /#projects for example?

Comment: Call on the same function when the document is finished loading (using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` e.g.). That way it sees that the page was loaded with the hash `#projects`, and it'll update the page accordingly.